# Sublinear growth of an optimal value

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

For a constant $C>0$, I am interested in the growth of

$$ K_n = \max_{p \in [0,1]^n} \quad p_1 C + \sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{1-p_j} \prod_{l=j+1}^np_l$$

as $n \to \infty$.

I conjecture:

1. The growth of $K_n$ is sublinear in $n$.
2. There is only one critical point of the above optimization problem in $[0,1]^n$.

I generated some support for 1. solving the problem numerically for $n = 2, ..., 60$, which yields the following plot for the optimal values as a function of $n$ (the kink at the end is due to some numerical problems of the optimizer).

[image]

The second point seems to be true from inspecting the solutions of the first order conditions of the above optimization problem. However, sadly I was not able to extract an analytic solution from these equations.

Any ideas to show 1. would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nice! Where did you come across this problem?